# How to retrieve a single record using icontains in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to query a single record using the following but I get a 500 error.

```
cdtools = CdTool.objects.get(product=product_record.id, 
                            platform=platform_record.id, url__icontains=toolname)
```

models.py

```
class CdTool(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

a model instance has an full url, but in my query 'toolname' is the short form (ie: google instead of https://google.com), so I'm trying to figure out what the correct query would be here.  I'm open to modifying models.py as long as there is no data migration stuff involved.

Comment: You should enable `settings.DEBUG` to get a traceback instead a server error: <https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#debug>. Then, what is the traceback you get?

Comment: Probably you are getting `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception on your query. At a quick glance try this `CdTool.objects.get(product_id=product_record.id, platform_id=platform_record.id, url__icontains=toolname)` if you are sure the instance exists in the DB indeed.

Comment: try the query in your shell